# Выборка 2-ух столбцов из таблицы БД и их вывод

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Ребята,выручайте.
Есть необходимость вывести столбцы из разных таблиц, используя JOIN.
Имеем: таблица 1 это sxgeo_cities, которая содержит id, region_id, name_ru
       таблица 2 это sxgeo_regions, которая содержит id, name_ru
Эти две таблицы соотносятся через region_id, значение столбца region_id таблицы sxgeo_cities, есть ни что иное как id из таблицы sxgeo_regions.
Есть желание получить вывод такого формата:

город1 регион1

город2 регион2

и так далее.

Для этого написал следующий код:

Для модели:

```
   public static function cities()
{

    sxgeo_cities')
    $sql ='SELECT sxgeo_cities.name_ru, sxgeo_regions.name_ru FROM sxgeo_cities
           LEFT JOIN  sxgeo_regions ON sxgeo_cities.region_id=sxgeo_regions.id;';

    $city = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)
            ->queryAll();
            return $city;
}
```

Для представления:

```
  <?php

use app\models\Geo;
?>

<?php foreach (Geo::cities() as $key):?>
    <?= print_r($key) ?> <br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Но желаемого результата не достиг, помогите решить проблему.

Comment: попробуйте использовать `INNER JOIN`. и вы забыли написать, у вас сам запрос не так выполняется, как вам хочется, либо какая-то другая проблема.

Comment: sxgeo_cities.name_ru AS city, sxgeo_regions.name_ru AS region

Comment: Действительно, оказалось,что просто надо было добавить аллиасы, ну и вьюху подправить для нужного мне вывода. Спасибо.